# bat file to get the latest version of a file

Tags: batch-file, version-control

I hope I could get some help here.
I am having a really long list of files with versioning (e.g. version 1, 2, 3, 4).
I am using a bat script to download these files from a server.
Is there anyway the bat script to check and download only the latest version? The file name structure is always the same, however the latest version of each period could be different and may vary from 1 to usually up to 10).

That's the script I am using.

```bash
copy \\server\folder\IAV95401*.CSV C:\folder\
set /p=
```

In the following screenshot you may see how the file naming looks like.

[image: Screenshot of the files in the folder]

I am currently downloading all the files and manually deleting the ones I don't need. And with hundreds of files, that's a lot of manual work.

I want the script to download only 3 files from the screenshot

```
IAV95402_2340_06__PANEL.CSV
IAV95402_2341_05__PANEL.CSV
IAV95402_2342_07__PANEL.CSV
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this solution should work for you:

```
@echo off
setlocal

rem Browse all files and keep just the last version of each unique files
for /F "tokens=1,2* delims=_" %%a in ('dir /A-D /B \\server\folder\IAV95402*.CSV') do set "last[%%a_%%b]=%%a_%%b_%%c"

rem Copy just the last versions
for /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('set last[') do copy \\server\folder\%%a C:\folder\
```

Comment: Thank you @aacini. That seems to work pretty well!